# steps in the proof, equation confusion

Tags: enumerate

So if I want to list out the steps of my proof in multiple locations if I use

```
 \begin{align} 
 fdsfdsf \\
 dsfds \\
 \end{align}

  blah blah 

 \begin{align}
 dsfdsf \\
 dsfds \\
 \end{align}
```

or even using equation instead of align, how come the numbers continue? So the first time I use it my steps will be 1-3, then the next time I use align or equation it wills tart from step 4?

How can I get it to restart the numbers in the steps?

Thanks!

Comment: `align` and all the rest of the numbered display math structures have continuous numbering by design.  the situation you describe is more appropriate for `enumerate`.  not relevant to this question, but important for proper vertical spacing: any display math environment shouldn't be separated from preceding text by a blank line.

Comment: What if I want the numbers to display on the right side of each step?

Comment: the equation counter *can* be reset with `\setcounter{equation}{0}` before each group, but then you will lose the ability to use `\ref` or `\eqref` with any accuracy because there will be too many instances with the same identifying value.

Comment: darn, seems like a simple request! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

Set it in a `\vbox` and save it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newsavebox{\myproof}
\begin{document}
\savebox{\myproof}{\vbox{%
 \begin{align}
 dsfdsf \\
 dsfds \\
 \end{align}}}
Here is my proof:

\noindent\usebox{\myproof}

and here is other stuff

 \begin{align}
 other \\
 stuff \\
 \end{align}

and here it the proof again

\noindent\usebox{\myproof}
\end{document}
```

[image]